# App crashes, when a thread is executed, Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to update textView in a time interval. ie The Texts changes as the time changes.The contents are stored in an Array, but when I try to do it from a thread , the app crashes . Here is the source code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final MessageList sample = new MessageList();
    sample.MessageMethod();

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();




    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             int x = 0;

            while (i<1)
            {
              if(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)%2==0)
              {
                  ++x;
                  TextView alertMessage =  

 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                  String parse = sample.message[x];
                  alertMessage.setText(parse);

              }

            }



        }
    }).start();
```

The app was successfully working before using a thread, I don't know if it's due to an error in initializing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: Its working fine now in Emulator, however, no text appears in the TextView

Comment: Where you declare i ?

Comment: I did declare it , final int i = 0 ; not with that I guess

Comment: i dont see any change in value of variable i and declaration as well it might result int infinite loop also dont change ui in thread change it uithread like some answers below

Comment: As below answers suggested, put your `alertMessage.setText();` inside `runOnUiThread()`

Answer (score 3):

You have to run this part of code in `UI Thread`:

```
 TextView alertMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
 String parse = sample.message[x];
 alertMessage.setText(parse);
```

It should be something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
     int x=0;
      while(i<1){
            if(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)%2==0){
            ++x;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             @Override
             public void run(){
              TextView alertMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
              String parse=sample.message[x];
              alertMessage.setText(parse);
             }
       });
       }
}
}
}).start();
```

Comment: String parse = sample.message[x]; here I get an error saying :variable 'x' is accessed from within inner class, need to be declared final, however when I declare it as final, ++x, wont work, as it cant assign value to a final variable, so any idea to fix this? :(

Comment: declare `x` inside `run` method and then create another variable. Assign that created variable to x and use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can not update UI from thread other than UI thread.

```
TextView alertMessage =  

 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                  String parse = sample.message[x];
```

**alertMessage.setText(parse);** this line is the issue.

replace your two lines of textview code with below one

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView alertMessage =  

 (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                  String parse = sample.message[x];
                  alertMessage.setText(parse);

        }
    });
```

you can only update UI element from UI thread. or you can call this line with the help of `runOnUIThread`

**Your code will become, something like this below**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int x = 0;

            while (i < 1) {
                if (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 2 == 0) {
                    ++x;
                    final String parse = sample.message[x];
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView alertMessage =

                            (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
                            alertMessage.setText(parse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: I guess you mean `you cannot update UI from thread other than UI thread.` in the first line ?

Comment: String parse = sample.message[x]; here I get an error saying :variable 'x' is accessed from within inner class, need to be declared final, however when I declare it as final,  ++x, wont work, as it cant assign value to a final variable, so any idea to fix this? :(

Comment: Check updated answer, it will work now

Comment: Still no Text is displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             int x = 0;

            while (i<1)
            {
              if(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)%2==0)
              {
                  ++x;
               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    TextView alertMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                    String parse = sample.message[x];
                    alertMessage.setText(parse);
                  }
              });

              }

            }



        }
    }).start();
```